# Angular splitter behaving glitchy

Tags: angular, flexbox, debouncing, splitter

I'm building a Splitter component in angular, using the **@angular/cdk/portals**. Everything works as expected, but I'm still having trouble with the resizing of the splitter. When moving the thumb, the offset increases for no apparent reason

I've created a complete reproduction [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5atdha?file=src%2Fsplitter%2Fsplitter.component.html). The project code is hosted [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/splitter-api/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/splitter/src). And a live demo can be found [here](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/splitter).

The splitter consists of panels inside a flexbox:

```
<div class="d-flex w-100" [class]="splitter-horizontal">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let panel of (panels$ | async); let index = index; let last = last">
        <ng-container *bsLet="(widthStyles$ | async) as widthStyles">
            <div class="split-panel overflow-hidden" #splitPanel [style.width]="widthStyles | bsElementAt:index">
                <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="panel.portal"></ng-template>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
        <div class="divider" (mousedown)="startResize($event, index, index + 1)" *ngIf="!last"></div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

`startResize` will compute the rendered widths once, and replace the `width: 100%` with the computed width for each panel:

```
const sizes = this.splitPanels
    .map((sp) => {
        const styles = window.getComputedStyle(sp.nativeElement);
        return styles.width;
    })
    .map((size) => size.slice(0, -2))
    .map((size) => parseFloat(size));

this.previewSizes$.next(sizes);
```

And the `widthStyles$` are coming from the `previewSizes$`:

```
this.widthStyles$ = combineLatest([this.orientation$, this.previewSizes$, this.panels$])
    .pipe(map(([orientation, previewSizes, panels]) => {
        if (previewSizes) {
            return [...Array(panels.length).keys()].map((v, i) => {
                if (i < previewSizes.length) {
                    return previewSizes[i] + 'px';
                } else {
                    return '100%'; // Equal width panels
                }
            });
        } else {
            return Array(panels.length).map((v, i) => '100%');
        }
    }));
```

On MouseMove, I'm updating a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
onMouseMove(ev: MouseEvent) {
    this.mousePosition$.next({ x: ev.offsetX, y: ev.offsetY });
}
```

And the rest of `startResize` is meant to update the `previewSizes$`:

```
this.mousePosition$.pipe(delay(5), takeUntil(this.stopResize$)).subscribe((mousePosition) => {
    const deltaX = mousePosition!.x - this.operation.startPosition.x;
    const sx = Array.from(this.operation.sizes);
    sx[this.operation.indexBefore] = this.operation.sizes[this.operation.indexBefore] + deltaX;
    sx[this.operation.indexAfter] = this.operation.sizes[this.operation.indexAfter] - deltaX;
    this.previewSizes$.next(sx);
});
```

For some reason the splitter is still growing faster than I'm moving my mouse. I've already tried using `debounce()` which is why I created the `mousePosition$` BehaviorSubject in the first place.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just had to use `ev.clientX` instead of `ev.offsetX` and the problem was fixed